# Python 3 I can't get my alarm to play

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a code I'm working on to automatically play my alarms at the times I specify. It also is playing some city sounds to help me sleep and while playing those sounds I can't get the while loop to end to have the alarm sound to play.

I tried to bring the while loop into the alarm function I've created but that didn't work but I'm fairly certain it has something to do with my while loops. But I'm thinking a fresh pair of eyes might do this code some good.

```
'''
Title: This is an alarm that perfectly lines up with my sleep schedule
Author: Riley Carpenter
'''
from pygame import mixer
import time
import os
import sys
import random
snoozeorstop = " "
Currenttime = time.ctime()
Hours1 = int(Currenttime[11:13])
Minutes1 = int(Currenttime[14:16])
Seconds = int(Currenttime[17:19])
optionalsongs = ["Pink Floyd     Time.wav","Alarm2.wav","Alarm3.wav","Alarm4.wav","Alarm5.wav","Alarm6.wav","Alarm7.wav","Alarm8.wav","Alarm9.wav","Alarm10.wav","Alarm11.wav"]
phrases = ["Wake up Riley!!!!","It's time to wake up it's time to wake up","HEEEEYYY WAKE UP","RILEY RILEY RILEY WAKE UP","1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 it is time to wake up","Riley more alarms are to come UNLESS you get up","OH WHEN SHALL I SEE JESUS you wanna not hear this again? Wake up","I'm so tired of telling you to wake up just wake up","A friend of the devil is somehow who doesn't wake up","Babe babe bae wake up"]
def playsound(soundfile):
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(soundfile)
    mixer.music.play(-1)
def stopsound():
    mixer.music.stop()
def alarm(hour,minute):
    print("")
    print("")
    print(random.choice(phrases))
    if Hours1 == hour and Minutes1 == minute:
        stopsound()
        playsound(random.choice(optionalsongs))
        print("")
        snoozeorstop = input("Do you want to stop the song? ")
        if snoozeorstop == "stop":
            stopsound()
citysounds = input("Do you want to play the soothing sounds of the city? ")
if citysounds == "y" or citysounds == "Yes" or citysounds == "Y" or     citysounds == "yes":
    playsound("Citys Night ambience sounds.wav")
else:
    playsound("Beginningsound.wav")
amount = 0
print("This is how many second has passed since this alarm was turned on")
while Hours1 != 5 and Minutes1 != 0:
    Currenttime = time.ctime()
    print(amount)
    Hours1 = int(Currenttime[11:13])
    Minutes1 = int(Currenttime[14:16])
    Seconds = int(Currenttime[17:19])
    amount += 1
    time.sleep(1)
alarm(5,00)
alarm(5,5)
alarm(5,10)
alarm(5,15)
alarm(5,20)
alarm(5,25)
alarm(5,30)
alarm(5,35)
alarm(5,40)
alarm(5,45)
alarm(5,50)
alarm(5,55)
alarm(6,00)
alarm(6,5)
alarm(6,10)
alarm(6,15)
alarm(6,20)
alarm(6,25)
```

Comment: you should explain the logic you are trying to implement

Answer (score 0):

Since the while loop is central to your program, why not write that piece of code first. When that works as intended you can add songlists etc.

As for checking for the time when the alarm should go off you might want to check out the `datetime` module which makes time calculations much easier. For example:

```
import datetime, time

start = datetime.datetime.now()
alarm = start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)   # Set alarm time 5 seconds from now

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()    # When is this?
    print(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))  # Print human readable time
    if now > alarm:       # Have I passed the alarm time?
        print('Alarm')    # Sound the alarm
        break             # Leave this loop
    time.sleep(1)
```